# Runtime identifier for a device architecture must be specified in order to publish this project (.NET MAUI)

Tags: maui

Hi any idea why am I getting this error when I try to publish to iOS [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFefV.png) Setup is already like this

am I missing something?

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>

<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
        <RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>
        <!-- Only needed when you have a need for entitlements -->
        <!-- <CodesignEntitlement>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlement> -->
        <CodesignKey>Apple Distribution: SAMPLE DISTRIBUTION (8C4ZRPEBJP)</CodesignKey> <!-- Should be your Certificate Distribution-->
        <CodesignProvision>MauiShellApplication</CodesignProvision>
        <ArchiveOnBuild>true</ArchiveOnBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: What command are you running? Does your project have project references?

Comment: Hi @GeraldVersluis I am running a dotnet publish release

Comment: I figured that ;) I meant the full command with all parameters and an answer to: does your project have any project references to other class libraries? If so, you have to specify the csproj of the .NET MAUI app explicitly in your `dotnet publish` command

Comment: Dotnet publish command stopped giving me errors when I closed visual studio.

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete my [PROJECT].csproj.user file at the root of the application folder. I ran into that issue previously but completely forgot about it. It seems like that file is getting settings that override the main csproj file and doesn't update when properties are changed. Hopefully this saves someone else the hours it took me to find remember the problem!